# How to set TTL to List Values in ServiceStack.Redis?

Tags: redis, servicestack, servicestack.redis

I Have a List in ServiceStack.Redis that I want to set a TimeSpan to expire it.

In the other word, how to call the following redis command in ServiceStack.Redis

> EXPIRE ListId ttl

my desired method is:

```
client.Lists(listId, timespan);
```

Is there any solution for my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the new Custom and RawCommand APIs on IRedisClient and IRedisNativeClient you can now use the RedisClient to send your own custom commands that can call adhoc Redis commands:

```
public interface IRedisClient
{
    ...
    RedisText Custom(params object[] cmdWithArgs);
}

public interface IRedisNativeClient
{
    ...
    RedisData RawCommand(params object[] cmdWithArgs);
    RedisData RawCommand(params byte[][] cmdWithBinaryArgs);
}
```

These Custom APIs take a flexible object[] arguments which accepts any serializable value e.g. byte[], string, int as well as any user-defined Complex Types which are transparently serialized as JSON and send across the wire as UTF-8 bytes.

```
Redis.Custom("SET", "foo", 1);
```

**Result:**

```
client.Custom("EXPIRE", "list-id", "100");
```

See [ServiceStack github](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#generic-apis-for-calling-custom-redis-commands)